# pycharm and open file suggested int

Tags: python-3.x, file, pycharm, with-statement

[image]
i have a def that open file from a directory, in it i have files and want iterate each file to make something

```
def read_decks_from_disk():
   deck_list = []
   basepath = Path("Decks\\")

   for filename in basepath.iterdir():
       if filename.is_file():
           with open(filename) as file:
               deck_info = file.read().splitlines()
               d = {
                   "nome": deck_info[0],
                   "formato": deck_info[1],
                   "prezzo": deck_info[2]
               }
           deck_list.append(d)

   return deck_list
```

when i use:

```
with open(filename) as file:
```

pycharm suggest my this:

```
Unexpected type(s): 
(Path) 
Possible types: 
(Union[str, bytes, int]) 
(Union[str, bytes, int, PathLike])
```

how can i fix this and why pycharm suggest my that even if the code works anyway?

Comment: I think a screenshot would be better.

Comment: added the screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please vote for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-30747 (thumbs up near the issue title)